# asp.net web API - no dll is available containing Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.IServiceLocator

Tags: asp.net, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api

So I want to set up dependency injection for my ASP.NET Web API project. Microsoft appear to have changed the way that DI is set up in MVC since version 3. Now I need to make a call like this:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.ServiceResolver.SetResolver(DependencyResolver);
```

`SetResolver()` accepts an object. What type of object?

When I run the application, I get an error telling me that the parameter passed in to `SetResolver()` must implement `Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.IServiceLocator`. Sure, I could do that. I'm sure it's not difficult.

But I can't create a class that implements `IServiceLocator` because I don't have the dll where the bloody thing is defined. Presumably it doesn't get included when you install ASP.NET Web API. So how on earth am I supposed to get the project to use my custom container for DI?

Comment: You might want to check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621316/what-is-the-iservicelocator-interface

Comment: IDependencyResolver is located in System.Web.Http.dll. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how it is in **beta** but it is gonna change (see [here](http://byterot.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/aspnet-web-api-series-part-4-dependency.html)):

DI is based on setting a dependency resolver (technically a service locator) on the HttpConfiguration object. This object is on the GlobalConfiguration object as a static property (web hosting) or in case of self hosting on HttpSelfHostConfiguration.

So in case of web hosting you would use:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.ServiceResolver.SetResolver(myResolver);
```

There are basically 3 options when it comes to registering a dependency resolver:

1. An instance of an object implementing `IDependencyResolver` dependency which has two methods: `GetService` and `GetServices`
2. An instance of an object which has these two public methods: `GetInstance` and `GetAllInstances`. No interface needed and Web API will use reflection to call methods.
3. Passing two delegates that return an instance or instances for a particular type

## EDIT

`IDependencyResolver` of Web API (*not* MVC) is located in `System.Web.Http.dll` in `System.Web.Http.Services` namespace.

Comment: I discovered subsequently that you can pass in an implementation of `System.Web.Http.Services.IDependencyResolver` and it works fine. Not sure what the error message about `Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.IServiceLocator` was all about.